# Zip code search wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

Is anyone aware of a plugin for word press that allows a csv file of zip codes to be loaded into a database, when a matching zipcode is searched for an optional action is taken (like showing a location)

We have a client who has various territories that serve certain areas.  They have provided us with a CSV file that shows the list of zip codes served for each location so a visitor only needs to search for their zip code and the company that serves that area would appear...

We don't need to show a map or anything like that just contact information for that location... I've been looking for an easy way to do this but have not found one yet.... Just wondering if there something out there before we do this with mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few plugins for CSV import, but they seem to be dealing with Post import and not custom data like ZIP code data.

This may not be the best way, but I would use a tool like Navicat to create a new table in your database for the zipcode data and then create a template in your theme that searches against that table to get your results.  I beleive the phpMyAdmin will also import a CSV into a table, and WordPress has a plugin for this, [Portable phpMyAdmin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/portable-phpmyadmin/).

Example: you could use [wpdb class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to connect to your ZIP Code table and return the results you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's only a few plugins for wordpress (mainly woocommerce) and other platforms that let you do this. The woocommerce service availability zip code search apps are focused on e-commerce. https://www.google.com/search?q=woocommerce+delivery+area+plugin

If you're looking for something more flexible, take a look at https://deliverychecker.co